# TYPO3 Extension Development: Composer Autoload Not Recognizing Custom Classes

Tags: php, composer-php, typo3, typo3-extensions

I'm currently developing a TYPO3 extension and facing an issue with the Composer autoloader not recognizing my custom classes. My goal is to use Extbase to fetch data and pass it to a Fluid template.

MY EXTENSION COMPOSER LOOK IKE THIS

```
{
  "name": "toumeh/mywebsite",
  "description": "my Website",
  "type": "typo3-cms-extension",
  "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "toumeh",
      "email": "toumeh@gmail.com"
    }
  ],

  "require": {
    "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content": "^12.4.0",
    "ext-pdo": "*"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "MyWebsite\\Classes\\": "Classes/"
    }
  },
  "extra": {
    "typo3/cms": {
      "extension-key": "mywebsite"
    }
  }
}
```

Am adding the class to the **ext_localconf.php** so i can use the Plugin inside of my typoscript setup

```
use MyWebsite\Classes\Controller\MyWebsiteController;
use MyWebsite\Classes\Domain\PageRepository;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility;

ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    MyWebsiteController::EXTENSION_NAME,
    MyWebsiteController::PLUGIN_NAME,
    [
        MyWebsiteController::CONTROLLER_NAME => PageRepository::PAGES
    ]
);
```

am getting the follwoing error

> Class "MyWebsite\Classes\Controller\MyWebsiteController" not found
>
> in /var/www/t3coredev/packages/mywebsite/ext_localconf.php line 11
> use MyWebsite\Classes\Domain\PageRepository;
> use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility;
>
> ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
> MyWebsiteController::EXTENSION_NAME,
> MyWebsiteController::PLUGIN_NAME,
> [
> MyWebsiteController::CONTROLLER_NAME => PageRepository::PAGES
> ]

1. am runing compose dump-autoload but it didn't work
2. exbase extension is inside of my root composer "typo3/cms-extbase": "^12.4.0"
3. Am pretty sure it is not permissions problem.

this a snapchat from my project structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFb7R.png)

am using typo3 composer version 12.4.8

Could someone help me understand why my classes are not being recognized by Composer's autoloader and how I can resolve this issue

Comment: In your code "MyWebsite" is the vendor and "Classes" is the package name. Which looks obviously wrong.
So you end up with the directory structure "Classes/Classes/Controller/MyWebsiteController".

Comment: i followed the example inside of the this repository
https://github.com/TYPO3-Documentation/t3docs-examples/blob/main/composer.json
even i used the same namespacing  and it dosn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the people who tried to help me. After checking everything, I found that the  running composer dump-autoload was not enough to discover the error. After I used composer update, I encountered a permission problem inside of my container

Answer (score 0):

`MyWebsite\Classes\Controller\MyWebsiteController` - I think this path is your problem. TYPO3 uses some naming conventions, and i'm pretty sure you need to cut the Classes part form that path.

```
use MyWebsite\Controller\MyWebsiteController;
```

Try it out!

Comment: i edited the namespacing like you said even i deleted the Classes completely and still having the same issues

  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "MyWebsite\\CMS\\": "Classes/"
    }

(1/1) Error
Class "MyWebsite\CMS\Controller\MyWebsiteController" not found

Comment: I‘m gonna look over your initial code and get back to you.